# Trying to find a book about AI embedded in human brain

Tags: story-identification, computers

There was a book I read when I was younger, probably around 2000 at a guess. Its main character was a woman who I seem to remember had a photographic memory but I can't remember how that tied into the plot.

The main storyline was about her working at this corporation where she would speak to her friendly computer and I seem to remember it was because she had a chip embedded in her brain. She would speak to her AI to get things done.

I can't remember much about what happened through most of the book but I think the twist was that the AI was evil and the baddy all along.

The front cover had a woman's head surrounded by metal tubes that may have been dipped in oil, so most of it was black. I thought it was called something like "Black Screen" but I've hunted far and wide and can't find it at all!

Anyone know the book?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A guess, with slim details from Wikipedia:

**Silver Screen** is a science fiction novel by Justina Robson, first published by Macmillan in **1999**. It features Anjuli O'Connell, employed as a psychologist to monitor an Artificial Intelligence named 901. She **has a photographic memory and perfect recall**. The story concerns events following the death of Roy Croft, Anjuli's colleague and friend. The book's themes include machine rights and evolution.

[image]

Comment: Spot on!! I found the UK cover art and recognized it immediately. Thanks!